# lower case not working on environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, devenv

Why can't you lower case a Node.js environment variable?

`process.env.someEnvironmentVariable.toLowerCase()
process.env.someEnvironmentVariable.toString().toLowerCase()`

not of these work

this however does but is there a cleaner way to do this:

```
let test = process.env.someEnvironmentVariable
console.log(`test: ${test.toLowerCase()}`)
```

This is another problem but the cause is probably different

```
 options = {
      branch: env.BRANCH,
      domain: env.DOMAIN,
      localDeployFolder: env.FOLDER
    }
    const opts = Object.assign({}, options)
    opts.branch = opts.branch.toLowerCase()
    const bucket = `${options.domain.toLowerCase()}-${options.branch}`
```

it doesn't lower case branch

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are you assigning those lines to variables and logging them like the last one?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. We do not know what *exactly* you expect the result to be. Do you expect that after calling `process.env.someEnvironmentVariable.toLowerCase()`, the value of `process.env.someEnvironmentVariable` is in lower case? If yes, that's not how JavaScript works (and has nothing to do with Node or env variables).

Comment: Just because they are not allowed to be changed.

Comment: did not assign them to variables...that's probably why.

Comment: is there a cleaner way than this 2 liner: let test = process.env.someEnvironmentVariable
console.log(`test: ${test.toLowerCase()}`)

Comment: I added another example of trying to lower case that I'm also having trouble with to make this question more interesting:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works as expected, because environment variables are always strings

```
❯ SOME_VAL=AbC1 node
> process.env.SOME_VAL.toLowerCase()
'abc1'
```

But if you define environment variable as `123`, `abc`, `1a`, of course `toLowerCase` will not work, as variables are already lowercased